I'm unable to be fully synced with the lightning network
I currently have a pruned Bitcoin Core node running on my Mac, and I have lnd running too.
Everytime I run lnd, I get flooded with these error messages in terminal: Query from peer ...:8333 failed, rescheduling:did not get response before timeout
I'm apparently unable to be fully synced with the lightning network. When I type "lncli getinfo" it says "synced-to-graph = false" and "synced-to-chain = true".
Here is how my lnd.conf file looks like:


debuglevel=info
maxpendingchannels=5
alias=YourNodeAlias
color=#68F442


bitcoin.active=1
bitcoin.mainnet=1
bitcoin.node=bitcoind


bitcoind.rpchost=localhost
bitcoind.rpcuser=admin
bitcoind.rpcpass=pass123
bitcoind.zmqpubrawblock=tcp://127.0.0.1:28332
bitcoind.zmqpubrawtx=tcp://127.0.0.1:28333


Here is how my bitcoin.conf file looks like:


server=1
daemon=1 
txindex=0
disablewallet=0

rpcuser=admin
rpcpassword=pass123
rpcbind=127.0.0.1   
rpcallowip=127.0.0.1
rpcport=8332

dbcache=1000  
maxmempool=300

listen=1
maxconnections=40

# ZMQ options
zmqpubrawblock=tcp://127.0.0.1:28332
zmqpubrawtx=tcp://127.0.0.1:28333


prune=20000


What do I need to do to fix the synced-to-graph issue? I just want to be able to run my own node and start making transactions immediately on the lightning network. Please help, been looking to fix this for many weeks.
